# Bing Map Invalid Credentials

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I created a Big Maps account and generated a `CredentialsProvider` key.

I have used this in a test application I wrote using the following:

```
<wpf:Map CredentialsProvider="MyCredentialsProviderKey" Width="250" Height="250"/>
```

The map shows up, everything works like clockwork.

I have moved all of this into my production project and I get `Invalid Credentials` whenever the map displays. Same key, same everything as the test project.

I am absolutely puzzled as to why this is happening. I have read some answers on here, some suggest setting the `Culture` property, I have done so, to no avail.

There obviously is some property or setting that is causing this to behave in this way.

Comment: When running in production, are you using the same network and computer as you used when testing? If not, it could be a network related issue that is blocking the authentication request.  Try watching the network traffic and watching the logging service URL from Bing Maps.

Comment: @rbrundritt same machine, same network. =/

Comment: Ok, in that case, verify the Bing Maps key is actually being set on the map. Make sure there wasn't a copy or paste error (i.e. missing last character).

Comment: @rbrundritt I posted an answer. Bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, although it's not elegant.

I created an `IMultiValueConverter`, which takes my `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Map` (Bing Map Control), and returns a `Location` (which is used by the Big Map Control).

Here is my XAML:

```
<wpf:Map Width="250" Height="250" x:Name="BingMapControl">
    <wpf:Pushpin>
        <wpf:Pushpin.Location>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LatitudeLongitudeToLocationConverter}">
                <Binding Path="LatitudeCoordinate"/>
                <Binding Path="LongitudeCoordinate"/>
                <Binding Path="." ElementName="BingMapControl"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </wpf:Pushpin.Location>
    </wpf:Pushpin>
</wpf:Map>
```

Within that converter I make this call:

```
var cp = map.CredentialsProvider as ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cp.ApplicationId))
    cp.ApplicationId = "MyBingMapKey";
```

It's still puzzling to me why the `CredentialsProvider` was not being set when I tried to do this within `XAML`.